# Dual Table SQL Query Help Needed

Tags: mysql

I have been given two tables with the following data:

ANIMAL TABLE:
Registration_Number
Sex

PEDIGREE TABLE:
Ped_Registration_Number
Name
Sire_Number

I need to write a sql statement that tells me the Name of a bull and how many bull calves and how many heifer calves he has produced.

I have no idea where to even start or if this can even be done with the table set-up.

The 'Sex' column with either be 'B' for Bull or 'H' for Heifer.  The Sire_Number tells us who the Sire (Bull) of the animal is.  The Sire_Number and Registartion_Number will be correlated.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Look into using `COUNT`, multiple `SELECT`, and `JOIN`.

Comment: No, it's a volunteer work project. This one is going to be much more complicated that your typical sql statement.

Comment: *how many bull calves and how many heifer calves he has produced.* - thi is not clear. I am sorry for my English but there is no **calves** in your tables and there is no definition of **he has produced**

Comment: Start by looking at the data in both tables. Pick a couple of bulls and figure out for yourself what the answer should be for each. From what I can see, it can be done with the data you have.

Comment: Basically, I need to count how many times the Sire_Number shows up in the Pedigree table, but then break it down further to figure out how many Ped_Registration_Number's are 'H' or 'B' from the Sex column that are from the same Sire_Number.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this query:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM pedigree p
INNER JOIN animal a
ON a.Registration_Number = p.Ped_Registration_Number
  AND a.Sex = 'B'
```

that will returns you names of all bulls.

And here is *the number of heifer calves* portion:

```
SELECT p.Name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT calves.Ped_Registration_Number) calves_number
FROM pedigree p
INNER JOIN animal a
ON a.Registration_Number = p.Ped_Registration_Number
  AND a.Sex = 'B'
LEFT JOIN pedigree calves
  ON p.Ped_Registration_Number = calves.Sire_Number
GROUP BY p.Ped_Registration_Number
```

And the very last approach:

```
SELECT p.Name,
  SUM(IF(h_b.sex='B',1,0)) calves_b,
  SUM(IF(h_b.sex='H',1,0)) calves_h,
FROM pedigree p
INNER JOIN animal a
ON a.Registration_Number = p.Ped_Registration_Number
  AND a.Sex = 'B'
LEFT JOIN pedigree calves
  ON p.Ped_Registration_Number = calves.Sire_Number
LEFT JOIN a h_b
  ON calves.Ped_Registration_Number = h_b.Registration_Number
GROUP BY p.Ped_Registration_Number
```

Comment: Thanks for the start. The main problem is counting the number of heifer calves and number of bull calves for each bull.

Comment: That's really close. It's returning the total number of calves for each bull.  Just need to get it to return a seperate column for Heifer calves (H) and bull calves (B) for each Sire.

Comment: check new update. but if you are student, you should really do those steps by yourself. Good luck with your project

Comment: Thank you Alex, that did it!  That query was way over my head.  I'm not a student, I'm a volunteer for a cattle association.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.Name,
SUM(IF(h_b.sex='B',1,0)) calves_b,
SUM(IF(h_b.sex='H',1,0)) calves_h,
FROM pedigree p
INNER JOIN animal a
ON a.Registration_Number = p.Ped_Registration_Number
AND a.Sex = 'B'
LEFT JOIN pedigree calves
ON p.Ped_Registration_Number = calves.Sire_Number
LEFT JOIN a h_b
ON calves.Ped_Registration_Number = h_b.Registration_Number
GROUP BY p.Ped_Registration_Number
```

Comment: this is not very polite to publish self answer, especially when it is not you who did the job ;-)

Comment: I am sorry Alex, I am not good at this.  How do I publish your answer as the correct answer?